# MYSQL select query with union

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run following query:

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT SecurityQues FROM reg_indi WHERE UserName='$usrnm') UNION (SELECT SecurityQues FROM reg_ac WHERE UserName='$usrnm');
```

But i am getting error in this syntax.

What is the error?

Comment: Put quotes around the query

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the query in quotes because for PHP it's a string, your parenthesis are wrong too:

```
$result = mysql_query(
               "SELECT SecurityQues
                FROM reg_indi
                WHERE UserName='" . $usrnm . "'
                UNION
                SELECT SecurityQues
                FROM reg_ac
                WHERE UserName='" . $usrnm . "'"
);
```

Btw `mysql_` extension is deprecated and removed from more recent PHP versions. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.